# Не создается таблица для сущностей

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Profile {

    @Id
    private String login;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    public Profile() {
    }

    public Profile(String login, String password) {
        this.login = login;
        this.password = DigestUtils.md5Hex(password);
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Имеется вот такая сущность, но при попытке обеспечить ей постоянство, появляется ошибка "table Roman.users doesn't exist".

persistence.xml выглядит так, заметил, что если ставить автоматическую генерацию ключа для сущности, то все нормально, в чем может быть проблема?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="bookChange" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>org.ceoro9.domain.Profile</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="ceoro9"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ROMAN"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Ошибка говорит что таблицы "users" нету в базе данных "Roman", попробуй в аннотации другое имя таблицы взять (просто в .xml стоит аттрибут "create-tables", должна автоматически создавать).

Answer (score 0):

Вероятнее всего проблема в том, что у вас нет мапинга. Хибернейт ничего не знает про ваш класс, который является сущность и, соответственно, не может создать таблицы в бд и работать с ней.
Добавьте в свой persistence.xml такую строку, где packageName - полный путь к классу Profile и все должно заработать

```
<mapping class="packageName.Profile"/>
```